# VDM++ type error: The state component "totalPrice" must not be used here

Tags: vdm++, vdm-sl

I wrote a code which is for the total price of book when multiplied by number of book and the book price in VDM++.

```
class Book

types
    public Title = seq of char;
    
instance variables
    private bookTitle: Title;
    private numberOfPages: nat1;
    private totalPrice : real;
    private price : real;
    private noofBook : nat1;
    
    inv numberOfPages >= 1 and numberOfPages <= 100;

values
    public Price: real = 20.50;

operations
    expCalculateTotalPrice: nat1 * real ==> real
    expCalculateTotalPrice (noofBook,price) ==
    ( 
        totalPrice := noofBook * price;
        return totalPrice;
    )

operations
    impCalculateTotalPrice(Book:real) price:real
      pre price > noofBook and price > 0
      post totalPrice = noofBook * price

end Book
```

the error is "The state component "totalPrice" must not be used here" which is

```
post totalPrice = noofBook * price
```

what is wrong with these?

Answer (score 1):

You need an external access declaration in an implicit operation definition, something like:

```
      ext
        rd noofBook:nat1
        wr totalPrice:real
```

if you want to write to the instance variable `totalPrice` like the explicit version.

Another thing that might confuse the tool is the name crash.
Your formal return value `price` is shadowing the instance variable of the same name, and the tool might consider the `price` in the precondition refers to the return value.

Comment: That "wt" should be "wr" :-)  The VDMJ derived tools (Overture, VSCode) allow access to any state in the absence of an "ext" clause, though restrict access if there is an ext clause.

Comment: thanks, @NickBattle. I corrected my answer.